How to build a polymorphic cluster based on a virtual one within the class hierarchy operator method + and demonstrate the mechanism of late binding?
In the base class I defined this operator (I declared it as virtual in the header file):
String String::operator+(String& other) {
    int newLength = getTrueSize() + other.getTrueSize() + 1;
    char* newStr = new char[newLength];

    copy(str, str + maxLength, newStr);
    copy(other.str, other.str + other.maxLength, newStr + getTrueSize());

    return String(newStr, newLength);
}

Here is the operator of the derived class:
String BigInt::operator+(String& other) {
    BigInt B2(other);
    BigInt result;

    long long res1 = arrayToNumber(digits, size);
    if (negative) {
        res1 = res1 - (res1 + res1);
    }

    long long res2 = arrayToNumber(B2.digits, B2.size);
    if (B2.negative) {
        res2 = res2 - (res2 + res2);
    }

    long long resultNumber = res1 + res2;
    if (resultNumber < 0) {
        result.negative = true;
        resultNumber = abs(resultNumber);
    }

    int* resultDigits;
    int resultSize;
    numberToArray(resultNumber, resultDigits, resultSize);

    result.size = resultSize;
    result.digits = resultDigits;

    char* resultChars = new char[resultSize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; ++i) {
        resultChars[i] = '0' + resultDigits[i];
    }
    resultChars[resultSize] = '\0';

    String s;

    s.str = resultChars;

    s.maxLength = resultSize;


    return s;
}

Move operator:
String& String::operator=(String&& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        delete[] str;
        maxLength = other.maxLength;
        str = other.str;
        other.str = nullptr;
        other.maxLength = 0;
    }
    return *this;
}

Main method:
#include "BigInt.h"
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    BigInt B1;
    String B2, BB;

    cout << "BigInt 1: " << endl;
    cin >> B1;

    cout << "BigInt 2: " << endl;
    cin >> B2;

    cout << "B1 = " << B1 << endl;
    cout << "B2 = " << B2 << endl;

    BB = B1 + B2;

    //BB = B1 + B2;
    //B4 = B1 - B2;
    //B5 = B1 * B2;
    //B6 = B1 / B2;

    cout << "B1 + B2 = " << BB << endl;
    //cout << "B1 - B2 = " << B4 << endl;
    //cout << "B1 * B2 = " << B5 << endl;
    //cout << "B1 / B2 = " << B6 << endl;

    return 0;
}

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Everything seems to be correct, but VS keeps throwing the delete_scalar.cpp exception. If the problem is not in the addition operator, then most likely in the movement operator
